# What is the best practices to use multi-thread as my requirements

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio-2012

Currently, I want to create new Window Service project by using VS 2012.

Every one minute (I use System.Windows.Forms.Timer control), there is one thread will start.

If after one minute and the thread does not finish, do nothing.

When thread start, it will work with 2 separate jobs, I want to use Thread for 2 these jobs.

Could anyone give me a best practices to approach the requirement.

I'm very appriciated for your helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

-Deadlocks
A deadlock occurs when each of two threads tries to lock a resource the other has already locked. Neither thread can make any further progress.

-Race Conditions
A race condition is a bug that occurs when the outcome of a program depends on which of two or more threads reaches a particular block of code first.

-Most computers now have multiple processors (also called cores), even small devices such as tablets and phones. If you know you're developing software that will also run on single-processor computers.

A class is not initialized until its class constructor (static constructor in C#, Shared Sub New in Visual Basic) has finished running.

Comment: Thanks for your advices. It means a lot.